# Image not showing on top of Background image? Bootstrap

Tags: html

For some reason my image isnt showing on top of my background image. here is my code below

html

```
<header>
</header>


  <section>
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row align-item-center">
          <div class="col-lg-5 text-center">
            <img src="img.png" width="400" alt="jordan1" >
          </div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </section>
```

css

```
header {
  height:100vh;
  background: url('backgroundimg.png') no-repeat center center/cover;
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the background image should have been attributed to the css body tag not header as such

```
body {
 height:100vh;
  background: url('backgroundimg.png') no-repeat center center/cover;
  
}
```